# Помогите разобраться с гемом Mechanize

Tags: ruby, gems

Помогите записать в базу, полученые данные

то что я делаю в консоли

```
  require 'mechanize'
  agent = Mechanize.new
  agent.get('http://koltsovo.ru/ru/informatsiya_o_statuse_gruza')
  form = agent.page.forms.first
  form['myform[x01]'] = '262'
  form['myform[x02]'] = '50339995'
  form.submit

  agent.page.search('.tTable01')
```

в ответ я получаю

```
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c4617a name="table" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x5c46148 name="class" value="tTable01">,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x5c4613e name="style" value=" width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px; ">] children=[
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c43da8 name="tr" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c43c86 name="th" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c43b5a "\n                     дата операции">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c43a7e name="th" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c4395c "\n                     состояние накладной\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c43862 name="th" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c43754 "\n                     примечание\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c43678 name="th" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c4356a "\n                     мест груза\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c4347a name="th" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c4338a "\n                     вес груза\n                 ">]>]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c431f0 name="tr" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c430ce name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c42fac "\n                   08.12.14 00:05\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c42ea8 name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c42db8 name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c42c96 "Груз прибыл в Екатеринбург">]>]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c42b1a name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c42a0c "\n                   Рейс: У6-702\nМест: 1\nВес: 11,7\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c4291c name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c4282c "\n                   1\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c4273c name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c4262e "\n                   11,7\n                 ">]>]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c424a8 name="tr" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c4235e name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c421c4 "\n                   08.12.14 00:05\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c4203e name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3bea0 name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c3bdb0 "Груз прибыл в Екатеринбург">]>]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3bc48 name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c3bb12 "\n                   Рейс: У6-702\nМест: 3\nВес: 3,3\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3ba18 name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c3b900 "\n                   3\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3b81a name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c3b70c "\n                   3,3\n                 ">]>]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3b5a4 name="tr" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3b496 name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c3b3a6 "\n                   09.12.14 14:15\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3b2b6 name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3b1a8 name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c3b00e "Груз выдан получателю">]>]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3ada2 name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c3ac80 "\n                   рейс: У6-702\nМест: 1\nВес: 11,7\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3ab7c name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c3aa5a "\n                   1\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3a988 name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c3a866 "\n                   11,7\n                 ">]>]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3a6a4 name="tr" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3a582 name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c3a41a "\n                   10.12.14 13:10\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3a348 name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c3a226 name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c3a0f0 "Груз выдан получателю">]>]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c33f34 name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c33e08 "\n                   рейс: У6-702\nМест: 3\nВес: 3,3\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c33d2c name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c33c00 "\n                   3\n                 ">]>,
# <Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x5c33ae8 name="td" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x5c339ee "\n                   3,3\n                 ">]>]>]>]
```

если я делаю

```
agent.page.search('.tTable01').each do |item|
  puts item
end
```

то получаю

```
 <table class="tTable01" style=" width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px; ">
    <tr>
        <th>
            дата операции</th>
        <th>
            состояние накладной
        </th>
        <th>
            примечание
        </th>
        <th>
            мест груза
        </th>
        <th>
            вес груза
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            08.12.14 00:05
        </td>
        <td><b>Груз прибыл в Екатеринбург</b></td>
        <td>
            рейс: У6-702
            Мест: 1
            Вес: 11,7
        </td>
        <td>
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            11,7
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            08.12.14 00:05
        </td>
        <td><b>Груз прибыл в Екатеринбург</b></td>
        <td>
            рейс: У6-702
            Мест: 3
            Вес: 3,3
        </td>
        <td>
            3
        </td>
        <td>
            3,3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            09.12.14 14:15
        </td>
        <td><b>Груз выдан получателю</b></td>
        <td>
            рейс: У6-702
            Мест: 1
            Вес: 11,7
        </td>
        <td>
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            11,7
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            10.12.14 13:10
        </td>
        <td><b>Груз выдан получателю</b></td>
        <td>
            рейс: У6-702
            Мест: 3
            Вес: 3,3
        </td>
        <td>
            3
        </td>
        <td>
            3,3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

сама таблица на сайте выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне записать данные из таблицы?

Указав что каждый `<tr>` это отдельная запись и в ней каждый `<td>` параметры для

```
 Movement.create!(
    created_at: дата операции,
    status_code: состояние накладной,
    description: примечание,
    pieces: мест груза,
    weight:вес груза
    )
```

Comment: Нудный обход [XML-дерева элементов Nokogiri](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri) и преобразование данных из него в обычные хэшмапы. Кормим результат в модель, готово. В чём конкретно проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем получилось как-то так

```
  require 'mechanize'
  agent = Mechanize.new
  agent.get('http://koltsovo.ru/ru/informatsiya_o_statuse_gruza')
  form = agent.page.forms.first
  form['myform[x01]'] = '262'
  form['myform[x02]'] = '50339995'
  form.submit

  agent.page.search('.tTable01 tr').drop(1).each do |row|
    movement = Movement.new

    movement.created_at = row.children[0].text.strip
    movement.status_code = row.children[1].text.strip
    movement.description = row.children[2].text.strip
    movement.pieces = row.children[3].text.strip
    movement.weight = row.children[4].text.strip

    movement.save
  end
```